# Highlight divs and spans with unstyled classes

Tags: css

How can I highlight all `span`s and `div`s in my html that have classes that are not styled?  this is for debugging purposes, to remind me what I will still have to fix up.

Comment: highlight how? with css? then they wouldn't be unstyled would they...

Comment: Seems like you're looking for this exact thing:  http://unused-css.com/  -  pretty sure doing what you're asking is fairly difficult on its own.

Comment: thanks, deryck.  this unused-css is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `border` to highlight the `span` and `div` elements

Do either:

```
span, div{
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Or:

```
.unstyledClassOfDivAndSpan{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like this. But it's not complete. Those elements with classes would still be highlighted, which is not what the OP seems to be looking for.

Comment: @icedwater OP has clearly stated in his question: "html that have classes that are not styled". I believe the answer is complete. Feel free to comment though.

Comment: Looks like I misread the question. I'm sorry. You can deduce from my interpretation below how I read it.

Comment: Looks like I misposted the question.  while this is a great way to highlight divs and spans in my document, it seems to highlight *also* those that have already been styled.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an `XXX` class to all the elements, then use this definition:

```
.XXX {
    border: 5em solid red;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Make sure this is at the end of the stylesheet so it doesn't get overridden. Then as elements are done, remove the `XXX` class.

Comment: Well then try the new suggestion :P

Answer (score 0):

**Please Use this Css Hover Style for highlight all spans and divs in your html**

```
div, span{
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: Black;
}

div:hover, span:hover{
    border: 1px solid Black;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**OR**
**Please Use this Css and Jquery Hover Function for highlight all spans and divs in your html**

```
.hilight{
    border: 1px solid red;
}


$(function(){
    $("spna div").hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("hilight");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not answering the question at all; if spelled correctly, it would cause spans and divs to be highlighted with a border when hovered over. Nice functionality, but try to read the question again.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but from my reading of the question I don't think the OP wants to have to hover over each item to check it. Maybe @IvoWelch can comment? (Gah, it's impossible to contact the OP from here.)